# [18.04][ATI] Screen artifacts and lags

Tags: graphics, radeon, gpu-driver

Hi :) I would like to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a old ASUS EeeTop (all in one desktop) but on the live system there are quite annoying screen artifacts. A few months ago I tried Ubuntu 16.04 on the same PC: same problem. Back then I installed v16.04 on a USB key in order to tweak the Radeon driver configuration but I didn't notice any changes... Gnome-Shell is also very laggy (as if hardware acceleration was not available). Here are some details:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v] [1002:9553]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v] [1043:029e]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

```
glxinfo | grep -i render
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 255 MB, largest block: 255 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 1021 MB, largest block: 1021 MB
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RV710 (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-20-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

Thank you :) .

Comment: @K7AAY I just want to note that the official Lubuntu website is [lubuntu.me](https://lubuntu.me) and not .net

Comment: I installed lxqt/openbox on the livecd: the performances are better (scrolling in Firefox is now acceptable) but unfortunately the artifacts/glitches are still there. I tried wayland too (gnome-shell and weston): same issue. I think it's a driver issue (radeon).

Comment: What happens when you install Lubuntu lubuntu.me ? Much lighter desktop, without the memory leak issues in the version of Gnome used by 18.04 Ubuntu